# Issues at EJB 3.x Sample Application with distributed packaging - Jboss 7.x

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

JBoss EAP 6.3.0.Alpha1 (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-4) 
 
jdk1.7.0_67 
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)

Created a sample EJB 3.x application

```
// Stateless Bean

    package ejb3inaction.example;
    import javax.ejb.Stateless;
    @Stateless
    public class HelloUserBean implements HelloUser{
      public String sayHello(String name) { return String.format("Hello %s welcome to EJB 3.1!", name); } }

//Remote class- Just a Interface for the bean
    package ejb3inaction.example;
    import javax.ejb.Remote;
    @Remote
    public interface HelloUser {String sayHello(String name);    }
```

Deployed in Jboss (Eclipse - Right click on Project - Run as - Run on server) - Below is the server log

```
16:26:21,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-11) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SampleEJB_3_2.jar" (runtime-name: "SampleEJB_3_2.jar")
16:26:21,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-16) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:4447
16:26:21,770 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-14) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
16:26:21,926 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-5) JNDI bindings for session bean named HelloUserBean in deployment unit deployment "SampleEJB_3_2.jar" are as follows:

    java:global/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean!ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser
    java:app/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean!ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser
    java:module/HelloUserBean!ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser
    java:jboss/exported/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean!ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser
    java:global/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean
    java:app/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean
    java:module/HelloUserBean
```

Created a SampleWebApplication and deployed at the same JBoss server where the above EJB 3.x app got deployed

java client

```
package ejb3inaction.example.utilization;
   import javax.ejb.EJB;
   import javax.naming.Context;
   import javax.naming.InitialContext;
   import javax.naming.NamingException;
   import ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser;

   public class HelloUserBeanClient{

   // EJB 3.x Client Injection      

   @EJB     
   private HelloUser helloUser;
   public String hello(){return helloUser.sayHello("Hello EJB 3.X");}

   //EJB Client Legacy Lookup support

   public String helloLegasySupport() throws NamingException{
   Context context = new InitialContext();
   HelloUser helloUser1 = (HelloUser)context.lookup("java:global/SampleEJB_3_2/HelloUserBean");
   return helloUser1.sayHello("Legacy support from EJB 3.X ");
            } }
```

JSP CLient - A view that in turn calls the java client

```
    <jsp:useBean id="ejbClient" class="ejb3inaction.example.utilization.HelloUserBeanClient"></jsp:useBean>
    <%
    try{
    out.println(ejbClient.hello());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    out.println("<br > ejbTest - hello " + e.getMessage());
    }
    try{
    out.println(ejbClient.helloLegasySupport());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    out.println("<br > ejbTest - helloLegasySupport " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Receiving class not found Exception while accessing the JSP client. However I could see both the classes(HelloUserBean.class, HelloUser.class) got generated and  available at "jboss-eap-6.3\standalone\deployments\SampleEJB_3_2.jar\ejb3inaction\example"

Error @ EJB 3.X Client Support - hello()

```
JBWEB000071: root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser from [Module "deployment.SampleWebApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373)
    org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118)
    ejb3inaction.example.utilization.HelloUserBeanClient.hello(HelloUserBeanClient.java:17)
    org.apache.jsp.ejbTest_jsp._jspService(ejbTest_jsp.java:78)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Error @ Legacy Support - helloLegasySupport()

```
JBWEB000071: root cause

    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ejb3inaction.example.HelloUser from [Module "deployment.SampleWebApplication.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
        org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:197)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:443)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:431)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:373)
        org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:118)
        ejb3inaction.example.utilization.HelloUserBeanClient.helloLegasySupport(HelloUserBeanClient.java:22)
        org.apache.jsp.ejbTest_jsp._jspService(ejbTest_jsp.java:78)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:69)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:365)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:309)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:242)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
```

Comment: Regarding the ear packaging, it is required to have them in standalone packaging ( ‘app war’ and ‘ejb jar’) for project needs. Uses “java:global” jndi namespace to make sure the lookup spot out the jndi reference as the app and ejb are not packaged into a ear. However, as @mendieta pointed out in below thread, the client app don’t have the visibility for the ejb classes though they are deployed in the same server(JVM), the lookup using global jndi namespace, also the class files got generated and available inside the ejb jar.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that your jsp client (which should be in a war file right?) has no visibility to your ejb.

Try putting both applications inside an ear file.. By doing that, the war will be able to see the ejb classes, so the classloader should have no problem finding HelloUserBean.

By the way, I would change the ejb injection (@EJB).. You should inject the interface (HelloUser), not the implementation.. You can find more info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html)

Comment: Changed the injection to get interface instead the implementation.

Comment: Regarding the ear packaging, it is required to have them in standalone packaging ( ‘app war’ and ‘ejb jar’) for project needs.  Uses “java:global” jndi namespace to make sure the lookup spot out the jndi reference as the app and ejb are not packaged into a ear. However, as you pointed out, the client app don’t have the visibility for the ejb classes though they are deployed in the same server(JVM),  the lookup using global jndi namespace, also the class files got generated and available inside the ejb jar.

Answer (score 0):

As @mendieta is suggesting, your *.war application doesn't 'see' the HelloUser class (thus the exception). You're not having any problem during compile time because either you have added the dependency in your IDE, or you're not providing your 'SampleWebApplication' with the class needed. If packaging into ear is not an option, what I suggest you to do is to extract the HelloUser interface to some java (jar) api-library and include it into both projects: EJB and 'SampleWebApplication'.